# XCode Requesting iPad Icons Even Though App Is for iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

So I made an app for the iPhone/iPod and I wanted to upload it to the app store but XCode is giving me this error:

[image]

I don't know why it's asking for this. I can't even find a place to put the icon, either.

Comment: What troubleshooting have you done? Have you cleaned and built the project? Delete derived data for the project? Ensured the deployment info doesn't have Universal as the Devices your project supports.

Comment: Turned out that I had my devices set to universal when I archived and I forgot to archive again when I change it to iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

An iPhone-only app can be installed on iPad, and the iPad springboard (app launcher) wants the iPad-sized icons for it.

Some of the documentation hasn't been updated to indicate that these icons are now required.  [Table 5-2 of the *iOS App Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1) does list the iPad-sized app icons as required on iOS 7 and later.

[Technical Q&A QA1686: App Icons on iPad and iPhone](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009882-CH1-ADDING_ICONS_TO_YOUR_APP) has a section titled “Adding Icons to Your App” that should help you “find a place to put the icon”.